# Swift 4: Filtering Array

Tags: arrays, swift

i am new to swift, currently practicing

here i have a plist file, **which has an Array Of Dictionaries**, each dictionary has one string, the plist has 3 records, it looks like this

```
item 0:
kurdi: Googlee

item 1:
kurdi: Yahooe

item 2:
kurdi: Binge
```

here's a image for the plist; 
[Screenshot 11:52AM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTtQT.png)

okay so the point is, when a user searches for `oo` for example two of the records contain `oo`, such as g`oo`gle and yah`oo`, i want to return an array of results,

for that case i used:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"hello", ofType: "plist")
let plistData = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
let objCArray = NSMutableArray(array: plistData!)

 if let swiftArray = objCArray as NSArray as? [String] {

     let matchingTerms = swiftArray.filter({
      $0.range(of: "oo", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil // here
        })
        print(matchingTerms)

    }
```

but unfortunately, when i print `matchingTerms` it returns nil
..
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are new to Swift please learn first not to use `NSMutable...` Foundation collection types in Swift at all. (The type *dance* `NSArray` -> `NSMutableArray` -> `NSArray` -> `Array` is awful). Use Swift native types. And instead of `NSArray(contentsOfFile` use `PropertyListSerialization` and the `URL` related API of `Bundle`.

All exclamation marks are intended as the file is required to exist in the bundle and the structure is well-known.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"hello", withExtension: "plist")!
let plistData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let swiftArray = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, format: nil) as! [[String:String]]
let matchingTerms = swiftArray.filter({ $0["kurdi"]!.range(of: "oo", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil })
print(matchingTerms)
```

Comment: Thanks vadian. so helpful

Comment: how to solve this in swift 4.0 It's crashing. let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "status = %@", DeviceUserStatus.New.rawValue) let sortedResults1 = (deviceUsers as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate) as NSArray, It's works fine in swift 3.3. swift 4.0 Crash says :  valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key status.

Comment: @JamshedAlam Don't use `NSArray` in Swift. The native `filter` method is more convenient. In Swift 4 you have to mark all properties as `@objc` when using NSObject - KVC.

Comment: My array is deviceUsers , declared like :     var deviceUsers = [EDeviceUser](). Should i declare it with :   @objc  var deviceUsers = [EDeviceUser]()  ? And then use the filtered(using: predicate) ?

Comment: @JamshedAlam No, please read the error message *... for the key **status***.  The property `status` must be marked as `@objc`. Please read also [SE-0160 Limiting @objc inference](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md)

Comment: @vadian , thanks a lot. Read that article and found my fixes way.

Answer (score 0):

Cast swift array to `[[String:Any]]` not `[String]`. And in filter you need to check the value of the key `kurdi`. Try this.

```
if let swiftArray = objCArray as? [[String:Any]] {
    let matchingTerms = swiftArray.filter { (($0["kurdi"] as? String) ?? "").range(of: "oo", options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
    print(matchingTerms)
}
```

Comment: If all dictionary values are `String` cast to `[[String:String]]`, not `[[String:Any]]`.

Comment: @vadian Yes If all dictionary values are `String`.